# Multiple devices associated with a single Samsung account

Tags: samsung, location-services

I am transitioning from iPhone to Samsung.
I mean to setup Find My Mobile.

For iOS, I can have one account and link many devices to the same account. Then, I can monitor/operate any of the devices from that account.

Is that possible with Samsung?

I read that something can be done with [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager), but I am asking specifically about Samsung accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and quite simple. Nothing special needs to be done.

In my specific case, I was stuck in a step prior to this due to other issues. See
[Access to Find My Phone locked in initial popup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162961/access-to-find-my-phone-locked-in-initial-popup)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just go to settings (if the device is already on), and go to accounts and add account (Gmail).

Comment: I would try that after solving http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162961/access-to-find-my-phone-locked-in-initial-popup

Comment: What does adding the the Gmail account have to do with the Samsung account and its device manager?