# Access to Find My Phone locked in initial popup

Tags: samsung, location-services

I am transitioning from iPhone to Samsung. I mean to setup Find My Mobile in two phones, say, P1 and P2.
What I did:

1. I Added the account in P1.
2. I entered [findmymobile.samsung.com](https://findmymobile.samsung.com), and before accessing my account it provides a popup with 3 "I agree to the terms and conditions" checkboxes, including accessing my screen unlock code (In iOS this was not needed, AFAIK). I have no problem in doing that for P2, but not for P1.
3. I mean to not proceed, for the time being, on P1, and go ahead with P2. But access to [findmymobile.samsung.com](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) is now locked in that popup, so I cannot proceed with adding/managing P2.

**How can I recover the initial [findmymobile.samsung.com](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) screen?**

I suspected that removing my Samsung account from P1 would freed internet access to [findmymobile.samsung.com](https://findmymobile.samsung.com). But doing that gives a warning (in Spanish, so I am not certain that the message in English is exactly this) that "Removing the account will delete all messages, contacts and other data from the device ¿Ok to continue?".

**Will I lose all that data from my phone?**

That is certainly not what I want from disconnecting the phone from my Samsung account.

Comment: You will lose any data specific to that account only,  so no, you likely won't lose anything removing a Samsung account. Why bother with Samsung's redundant tool, this is a basic function of your Google Account, look into Android Device Manager.

Comment: @acejavelin - I have never (at least voluntarily) synced anything with that Samsung account. So I guess from your answer that I can safely remove that account. And I did not know about Google Accounts.

Comment: Android was designed to work with Google, Samsung just throws there redundant services on top of it... Your Google account (Gmail) can be used to maintain cloud backups of contacts, calendar, system settings, wallpaper, installed apps (and settings for some apps), location services, device location management, cloud storage and much more. I would suggest investing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is by confirming all 3 checkboxes for P1, thus being able to move on to my Samsung account. I could link P2 as well.

Then I removed the Samsung account from P1, and I did not lose my contacts (perhaps since I did not set it up for syncing contacts).